# Error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token despite not include-loop

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I have a class `RenderMachine` which includes `RenderObject` and vice versa. I know there have been tons of questions about this error, but the solution for this doesn't do anything.

They say the error is mostly because a include-loop but I don't have one because in the `RenderObject` header I only allocate memory for a pointer to RenderMachine and vice versa.

```cpp
RenderObject.h
#pragma once
#include "RenderMachine.h"

class RenderObject
{

public:
    RenderObject(RenderMachine* rm){}

};
```

```cpp
RenderMachine.h
#pragma once
#include "RenderObject.h"

class RenderMachine
{

public:
    void add(RenderObject* renderObject);

};
```

The exact error is

```cpp
error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
RenderObject(RenderMachine* rm)
                          ^
```

Edit:

```cpp
#include "RenderMachine.h"
class RenderMachine;

class RenderObject : public sf::Drawable
{

private:
    int renderId;

public:
    RenderObject(RenderMachine* rm){ (*rm).add(*this); }
    int getRenderId() const { return renderId; }
```

```cpp
#include "RenderObject.h"
class RenderMachine
{

std::vector< std::vector<sf::Drawable*> > renderVector;

public:
    void add(RenderObject* renderObject);
```

And RenderMachine.cpp

```cpp
#include "RenderMachine.h"
void RenderMachine::add(RenderObject* renderObject)
{
    renderVector[(*renderObject).getRenderId()].push_back(renderObject);
}
```

Comment: have you tried a forward declaration?

Comment: Yes I already tried that and when the constructor definiton is empty it works just fine but when I call a method of RenderMachine I get this error: `error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘class RenderMachine’`

Comment: @Che You should probably show that code with the particular error instead. Without forward declaration it can clearly not work. But if it doesn't work with forward declaration either, there must be a second, different, issue.

Comment: For the question as is, comment aside, I would say possible duplicate of [Resolve build errors due to circular dependency amongst classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625799/resolve-build-errors-due-to-circular-dependency-amongst-classes) Especially second half of the top answer.

Comment: For the edited question, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/625801/11941443) on the same duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your call to `add` in the constructor of `RenderObject` should be done when `RenderMachine` is known (when it's a complete type). This goes for all calls to an object of the other type that you now have in your header files. Like this:

```
// RenderObject.h
class RenderMachine;

class RenderObject {
public:
    RenderObject(RenderMachine* rm);
};
```

```
// RenderMachine.h
class RenderObject;

class RenderMachine {
public:
    void add(RenderObject* renderObject);
};
```

```
// RenderObject.cpp
RenderObject::RenderObject(RenderMachine* rm) {
    rm->add(this);
}
```

```
// RenderMachine.cpp
void RenderMachine::add(RenderObject* ro) {
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a classic chicken-and-egg problem. The compiler cannot parse one header without first parsing the other header, because the classes in the headers refer to each other.

The solution is to use a forward declaration like this:

```
#include "RenderMachine.h"

class RenderMachine; // forward declaration

class RenderObject
{

public:
    RenderObject(RenderMachine* rm){}

};
```

Comment: Yeah I did that but still there is this `error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘class RenderMachine`error

Comment: Is that error for RenderObject.h or RenderObject.cpp?

Comment: @LeeJenkins Note that there doesn't seem to be a `RenderObject.cpp` file. The constructor definition is inline in the header file here.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Right you are! I lazily scrolled up to Ted Lyngmo's answer -- my mistake. Of course, that is the source of the OP's error: the compiler cannot complete the constructor in one header because the code depends on the other header. Chicken and egg. The solution, along with the forward declaration, is to put the constructor in a cpp file, as Ted Lyngmo has done.